# How to open another class in gdx game

Tags: libgdx

Ok, I'll just come out with it. I'm extremely new to Android coding. I'm also doing it solely with AIDE on my phone.

I want to open another class labeled aboutgame.java

I'm not sure how to post my code, but here goes.

```
package com.bernco.screenoff;

import com.badlogic.gdx.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;




public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener
{

    Texture texture;
    Texture pwrdby;
    Texture about;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    SpriteBatch pwrbtch;
    SpriteBatch abtbtch;







    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("dark-android.jpg"));
        about = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("about.png"));
        pwrdby = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("powered-by.png"));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        abtbtch = new SpriteBatch();
        pwrbtch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {        
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        abtbtch.begin();
        abtbtch.draw(about, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - about.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - about.getHeight() / 2,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 8, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 8);

        abtbtch.end();

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 80, 0, 
                   Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 1, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2);
        batch.end();

        pwrbtch.begin();
        pwrbtch.draw(pwrdby, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 80, 0,
                    Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3);
        pwrbtch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume()
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: Suggestion: invest in a good LibGDX _book_ and follow the examples in in step-by-step. Personally I'm really enjoying "Beginning Game Development with LibGDX".

Answer (score 3):

welcome to StackOverflow!

At a high level, what you need for a multi-screen game is one class to represent your application, and a bunch of other classes to represent the different screens in your game.

In libGDX, this means that instead of your `MyGdxGame` class implementing `ApplicationListener`, you want to have it extend the [`Game`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.html) class. This is a utility class that libGDX provides that gives you some of the framework code needed to manage screens. Instead of drawing itself, this class will tell one of your screen classes to draw itself instead. Then when you want to change screens, you call `Game#setScreen(...)` to point it towards a new screen.

Each of your screen classes then will need to implement the [`Screen`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) interface, which will show you the methods you need to implement for them to work with your game.

I recommend you take a look at two tutorials on the official libGDX wiki: [A Simple Game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game) and [Extending the Simple Game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game). They give examples for both Desktop and Android, and the latter walks you through examples of how to use `Game` and `Screen`.

Comment: So what you're saying is that instead of saying "implements ApplicationListener" it should say something like "extends MyGdxGame"?  I'm sorry, I'm just learning. Lessons and examples are few and far between. I can only guess at much of what you say (at least on how to apply it to my own app). I've only been at this for 2 weeks. But thank you so very much for your help

Comment: Close- it should be `MyGdxGame extends Game`. To give me a little more context here, do you have much experience with either Android or Java?